# The requiredfeild vaildator should not validate if the control is disabled

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am having two controls in that i have set the required field vaildators for that controls.my issues is for the time being i have set that two controls disabled but this required validator is checking if the two  controls in the disabled mode.i am checking that required field validator while clicking the save button.how to overcome this?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" Width="150" runat="server" TabIndex="17" Enabled="false"
  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="--Select Company--"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"
  ValidationGroup="UserDetailsGroup" InitialValue="--Select Company--" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

texboxcontrol:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="AcquiredDate" runat="server" Width="150" TabIndex="18" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="AcquiredDate"
    ValidationGroup="UserDetailsGroup" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

here the save button is the image button?

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Save" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/save-button.gif"
   OnClick="Save_Click" TabIndex="41" ValidationGroup="UserDetailsGroup" />
```

How to overcome this pblm either in server side or client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the Validators:

```
RequiredFieldValidator3.Enabled = DropDownList1.Enabled
RequiredFieldValidator2.Enabled = AcquiredDate.Enabled
```

Comment: i should write this coding in the button click a?

Comment: Are the controls disabled by default? Then i would make the validators disabled by default too. And if you enable them, enable the validtors too as in my sample showed.

Comment: RequiredFieldValidator3 how to get this in the serverside coding

Comment: You can access all controls that are runat=server and that have a ID on serverside via their ID's.

Comment: RequiredFieldValidator3 i am not getting this in the serverside

Comment: This should work, but if it doesn't try to change the ID, save and rechange it back to its original id. Sometimes Visual Studio spins.

Comment: ya i got it it working after a long time only i am getting the * for that two controls while clicking save button i dont know why?for the other controls i am getting soon...

Comment: if the two controls are been enabled for the firsttime when i click the save button it is not working..then if i click the button without doing anyaction and click it again then the two requiredfeildvalidators are working......?